# How to prolong the expiration of an azure token returned by python's CachingInteractiveBrowserCredential?

Tags: security, azure-active-directory

I am writing a desktop app to connect to azure blob storage with AD credentials.

I created and configured an application in Azure AD and can connect and perform operations against the storage:

```
from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.common import TokenCredential
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential

credential = TokenCredential(InteractiveBrowserCredential(...).get_token("https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation").token)

blob_client = BlockBlobService(account_name="...", token_credential=credential)

for c in blob_client.list_containers():
    print(c.name)
```

The above code pops up a browser and after I perform authentication, control returns to the executing code and everything works great.

The problem is that the obtained token expires in one hour, which is not tolerable for the end-users.

I considered two options, none of which seems feasible:

1. prolong the lifetime of the token (less desired)- didn't find documentation on how to do this.
2. Use a refresh token to obtain a new token. However, no refresh token is returned (it is discarded inside the get_token method), and even if I were able to obtain it, it is not clear how to use this API with a refresh token.

I'll appreciate any help.

I am using python 3.7 and azure-storage-blob 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclaimer, I'm quite a Python noob.
But I had a look at the source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/ab56b7c4ff9dc6ffa6f248d9061af4b1b275ffe2/sdk/identity/azure-identity/azure/identity/_credentials/browser.py#L52.

If you call:

```
InteractiveBrowserCredential(...).get_token("https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation")
```

It looks like it'll first check the cache.
If it finds a token there, it'll return that.
Otherwise it'll pop a browser.

So I'm thinking you could just call `get_token` before every call.
That way azure.identity will automatically get you a new token if needed.
At least this is how it works on the .NET side.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Even if caching was working, it does not survive a restart. But more importantly, the refresh token is discarded by the code so it has no means of silently obtaining a new token.